# Uri to URLencoded string

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object of Uri. How to get the Urlencoded string? Any builtin support of Uri class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` or `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` in System.Web

Answer (score 1):

Use `Uri.EscapeDataString()` and `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` static methods of `Uri` class.